# XSL padding fixed length

Tags: xslt, pad

I have the following XSL code

```
<xsl:value-of select="arinc:FlightPlan/arinc:Waypoints/arinc:Waypoint/concat(@waypointName, ',',arinc:Altitude/arinc:EstimatedAltitude/arinc:Value, ',', format-number(hours-from-duration(arinc:CumulatedFlightTime/arinc:EstimatedTime/arinc:Value), '00'), '.',format-number(minutes-from-duration(arinc:CumulatedFlightTime/arinc:EstimatedTime/arinc:Value), '00'),'...')"/>
```

the result should be fixed length set to 3500 characters. Any ideas please?
Sample Input:

```
</Waypoint>
<Waypoint countryICAOCode="EG" sequenceId="6" waypointId="ADMAG" waypointLongName="ADMAG" waypointName="ADMAG">
  <Coordinates latitude="+184442" longitude="+1774">N5114.0 E00029.6</Coordinates>
  <Airway type="RNAV_SID">ADMAG1X</Airway>
  <Altitude>
    <EstimatedAltitude>
      <Value unit="ft/100">111</Value>
    </EstimatedAltitude>
  </Altitude>
  <CumulatedFlightTime>
    <EstimatedTime>
      <Value>PT0H9M51S</Value>
    </EstimatedTime>
```

The requested output can contain several `Waypoint`s with up to 3500 characters. There are also some more fields needed to pad to the fixed length. This one is given for example.

Comment: Please post a small example of the input, and the expected output. -- P.S. 3500 characters?! Surely that means you need to pad each value to a fixed length of its own, **before** you concatenate them?

Comment: http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_pad-string-to-length.html has an example,

Comment: Please give a proper, complete sample input xml. Do you need a single line of text for your statement? And the result of this, should be padded at 3500 chars?

Comment: pls find attached input file above. As a result, there is a single line of text padded at 3500 characters requested

Answer (score 0):

[Function Substring](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring)

`substring("12345", 1, 3)` returns `123`

Comment: I was thinking rather about using pad, because this field and some more other should be left justified also

Comment: xslt 2.0 available?